# How to align two buttons in the center

Tags: center, input-button-image

I am new to web development and wanted to practice a little bit doing side projects. I am trying to re create the google main page and can't figure out how to put the two buttons below the input text engine. I have searched online and tried, text-align, margin: 0 auto and none of[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKMR2.png) it has worked.

Comment: You should post a minimal, reproducible example of what you have so far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this is a bad question but I won't down vote it.  What you should do is start the question over but ask something very specific such as: I am trying to put two buttons together, like this google image of the two buttons together.  Show you attempted some code and what part of that code is breaking.  Make sure your user tags include css and html I don't know what center input buttons means.